# How to redirect from observer in after logout in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect, logout

I have created an observer for customer_logout event and on its observer, I want to redirect the customer to a specific page. how can be done ?
In Magento1.9.x as

```
   $observer->getControllerAction()->setRedirectWithCookieCheck($url);
```

I want replacement of above for the Magento2.x.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
namespace HS\OneStepCheckout\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckoutCartAddProductComplete implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $response;

    public function __construct(
        ..\\
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        ..\\
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $url = "pass correct url here";
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->response->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: got following error : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResponse()

Comment: have you remove var folder?

Comment: No, should I need to recompile ??

Comment: Same issue, I think $controller doesnot get value from observer  any alternate solution.

Comment: you can get hint from core file, magento2/vendor/magento/module-captcha/Observer/CheckUserLoginObserver.php

Comment: ok, Let me try once. Thanks for quick feedback.

Comment: This is the working solutions. plz check it.

Comment: Thanks man, its working. This line is useless here i think:
       $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
why we use exit, please can you little bit explain ??

Comment: It doesn't gets signout ??

Comment: you can check after remove exit from observer and try

Comment: No, doesnot work.

Comment: sorry, i have try same code and its working for me. i doesn't know what issue have fetched. You can check for log if any error are genertae

Comment: There is no any error if I removed exit its works fine  but it does not redirect , it executes its default.

Comment: I think you have to keep exit at end of redirect and check for issue debuging

Comment: perfect answer!!! its only working after applying cache:flush! made my day! +1 :)